# how to convert json into json string with spacing preserved?

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, gson

I want to convert Json into Json String like below in Spring-Boot application. How to do this? Thanks in advance.

```
{
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "delectus aut autem",
    "completed": false
}
```

Convert the above as:

```
"{\"userId\":1,\"id\":1,\"title\":\"delectusautautem\",\"completed\":false}"
```

Here i am converting json String to JsonNode but not getting desired result.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = json_view.toString();
JsonNode processed_json = mapper.readTree(json);
```

Comment: `ObjectMapper` is not a Gson class, are you sure the tags on your question are correct?

Answer (score 0):

I read the above json into jsonNode and convert again to json  String .

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper= new ObjectMapper();
        String json = """
                {
                    "userId": 1,
                    "id": 1,
                    "title": "delectus aut autem",
                    "completed": false
                }
                """;
       JsonNode jsonNode= objectMapper.readTree(json);
     String jsonConverted=  objectMapper.writeValueAsString(jsonNode);
     System.out.println(jsonConverted);
```

and ouput will be
{"userId":1,"id":1,"title":"delectus aut autem","completed":false}